# Smart SQL Query to compute sum of multiple columns

Tags: sql, select

I have 50 bank accounts: *B1, B2, B3, ... B50*. Each of them has a last modified date. *D1, D2, D3,..., D50*.
I want a query that can give me the sum of all these bank accounts after each account last modified date.
The naive version of this query would be:

```
select sum(balance)
from ((select balance from accounts where address=B1 and lastModifiedDate>D1)
union
(select balance from accounts where address=B2 and lastModifiedDate>D2)....  
(select balance from accounts where address=B50 and lastModifiedDate>D50))
```

what is a smarter way to write this query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when address=B1 and lastModifiedDate>D1 then balance else null end)....
```

Comment: Add whatever logic you'd like into the conditions